# how to copy a file to given path during install windows .net application

Tags: .net, windows, installation

I'm creating a setup to install a window .net application. I manged to install all application assembly to given location ([ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer][ProductName]). Any way there is a separate xml file I need to copy to a another location. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create an Installer Class and override the [Commit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.install.installer.commit.aspx) method, in there you can write the code that copies the files. In your MSI project on the [Custom Actions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d9k65z2d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) editor add the installer class Commit method.

Answer (score 0):

MSDN provides excellent documentation on how to do this.
You'll need to add a custom folder as described here:
[How to: Add and Remove Folders in the File System Editor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/x56s4w8x%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> To add a custom folder
>
> In the folder list of the File System Editor, select the File System
>   on Target Machine node.
>
> On the Action menu, point to Add Special Folder, then click Custom
>   Folder or Web Custom Folder.
>
> The new folder is highlighted in the folder list.
>
> Type a name for the custom folder.

Then you can add your file as described here:
[How to: Add Items to a Deployment Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/z11b431t%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

> To add a project output or file to a deployment project
>
> Open the File System Editor. For more information, see How to: Open
>   the Deployment Editors.
>
> Select a folder on the target computer where the item will be
>   installed.